# 'gcc -lXext' succeeds but libXext appears not to be linked

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, crash, dynamic-linking

A binary has been linked with gcc using:

`gcc notion.o -Wl,-whole-archive ../ioncore/ioncore.a
-Wl,-no-whole-archive -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11 -lXext -lSM -lICE
-Wl,-whole-archive -L../libmainloop -lmainloop -lextl -ltu
-Wl,-no-whole-archive pkg-config --libs lua5.1 -ldl -lm -lrt -Xlinker
--export-dynamic -o notion`

Linking succeeds - however, when starting the application, a user reports a crash due to an undefined symbol (`XShapeCombineRectangles`). `XShapeCombineRectangles` should be available in libXext.

Indeed, checking with 'ldd', Xext is not listed as a shared library dependency for this user:

```
linux-gate.so.1 => (0x0068f000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00ec7000)
liblua5.1.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblua5.1.so.0
(0x00226000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x005da000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x005e1000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x0032c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00335000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x007d6000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00882000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
(0x006dc000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00110000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6
(0x00dd8000)
```

When I compile the application myself, ldd *does* show libXext, and indeed does not crash.

What could be going on here?

(More context: this bug was reported at http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3427206&group_id=314802&atid=1324528 )

Comment: Are you sure you're not linking in a static libXext library, and not a shared library ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but running with `-Wl,-y,XShapeCombineRectangles` shows `/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so` so I'd say it's linking dynamically, right?

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that your linker (or gcc) automagically adds `--as-needed` behind the scenes, and that on your system `XShapeCombineRectangles` comes from some library *other* than libXext.

You can find out which library defines the `XShapeCombineRectangles` symbol in your link: just add `-Wl,-y,XShapeCombineRectangles` to your link line.

Adding `-v` will show if any `--as-needed` arguments are at play or not.

You may be able to force the final executable to reference `libXext` by appending `-Wl,--no-as-needed,-lXext` to the link line.

**Update**: I misunderstood the question (and you've formulated it exceedingly poorly).

To restate:

1. the application links and works correctly on OPs system, and `ldd

   app` shows dependency on libXext
2. the application also links and starts correctly on end-user system, but `ldd app` does *not* show libXext
3. when the application attempts to `dlopen("de.so", ...)` on end-user system, this fails with `de.so: undefined symbol XShapeCombineRectangles`

If above points are correct, it's likely that

1. The end-user system has `libXext.a`, but not `libXext.so`
2. The main application does not call `XShapeCombineRectangles`, only code in `de.so` does
3. When `de.so` is linked, there is no `-lXext` on *its* link line.

Either installing `libXext.so`, or linking the main application with `-u XShapeCombineRectangles` will likely solve the problem.

To understand the problem, you might want to read [this](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).

My guess is that `XShapeCombineRectangles` is not referenced from main executable, hence not pulled from the `libXext.a` "bookshelf", hence not exported from the main executable despite `--export-dynamic`.

Comment: Hmm, `nm /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.a | grep XShapeCombineRectangles` actually did turn up `XShapeCombineRectangles` in `libXext` - but i'll pass this on, thanks!

Comment: since he says that on his system, libXext *is* listed, I suspect that on his system, the main application for some reason depends on a function of libXext and so as-needed does link against it. For the other users system, the main executable perhaps does not depend on libXext, so does not link against it (thus --no-as-needed may be needed like you say). Perhaps a dlopen in the app of a broken .so file (one which does not list libXext as DT_NEEDED) causes the crash?

Comment: Your restatement of the problem is correct, thank you. 1) running with `-Wl,-y,XShapeCombineRectangles` ends with `/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so:
definition of XShapeCombineRectangles`, so this does not appear to be the case. 2) This is indeed the case (well, `de.so` and `mod_dock.so`). 3) This is indeed the case (de.so is built by `gcc -shared  -lrt init.o draw.o font.o colour.o brush.o fontset.o style.o precompose.o exports.o  -o de.so`).

Comment: Indeed, when I explicitly add --as-needed to the linker flags I can reproduce the problem - so in my case the main program doesn't directly use libXext either. The neat thing to do would be to explicitly add --as-needed, and also add -lXext when linking modules that might require it, right?

Comment: @Arnout you don't need --as-needed or --no-as-needed if you properly add -Xext when linking the modules you load with dlopen. The --no-as-needed is just a workaround if you cannot for whatever reason properly link the modules.

Comment: Indeed I don't need `--as-needed` per se, but it's still an improvement right? 2 reasons: 1) it might drop unused libraries 2) it makes the build more predictable (no longer `--as-needed`-behavior on some machines and not on others)